# best fit memory allocation block size

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system, allocation, best-fit

I'm trying to simulate an OS.

Say I'm given `x` bytes of memory.

How would I go about designing a best fit memory allocation system?

I am planning to create an array to store multiple memory block objects, each containing some amount of the total memory size. Example:

<sub>Total size is 100 bytes</sub>

b1=20, b2=30, b3 =10, b4= 15, b5 =25

1. Is there a specific way to go about generating each block size?
2. What happens if a process requires 50 memory? None of the blocks will be able to support the process. Should I just refuse the process since none of my blocks can support it or should I merge blocks etc.

Comment: Answer to 2-> You should think about defragging your blocks to form a bigger coalesce of block which would serve the request. You should try to support the process, till it is within the capacity of the RAM and SWAP space.